# Greasemonkey and jQuery 1.4.2 not working

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I am attempting to use Greasemonkey and jQuery 1.4.2. When I install the Greasemonkey script jQuery is definitely downloaded and appears in the scripts directory. However the below code doesn't append anything to elements with the class `PAPAGETITLE`. What am I doing wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           PS Timesheet
// @namespace      http://www.steelebit.com/gmscripts
// @description    Used to fix a terrible implementation
// @include        https://intranet.site.com/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

// Append some text to the element with id #someText using the jQuery library.
$(".PAPAGETITLE").append(" more text.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

As of Greasemonkey version 0.9.1, jQuery 1.5.1 seems to work fine in all of my scripts and tests so far.

---

Greasemonkey does not work with jQuery 1.4 without some hacking.

Use jQuery 1.3.2.

See: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error (and others).

Answer (score 1):

I've blogged about [another possible solution here](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script), which works with jQuery 1.4.*