# Remove Server-side Generated Banner Ads - Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, adblock

I am on an airplane flight and they are forcing every page (including this Stack Overflow page) to have a banner at the top with their ads on it.

Here is the code I have for my UserScript in Firefox, but it isn't working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SW Ad remover
// @namespace      seangates.com/sw_ad_remover
// @include        *
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('script[src$="swa.py"]').remove();
 $('div[id^="__swa"]').hide();
 $('body').css('padding',0);

 console.log('working');
});
```

Any thoughts as to why this would not be working?  I can't even get a console.log to work even if I put it in the beginning of the ready() block.

Comment: PS:  [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/) is a kick-ass add-on, and should also work well for this.

Comment: I can already block the ads, but I still get a massive banner at the top of any page I visit with the airline's logo, etc.  I won't get a chance to test this again for a few days, but will let you know when I do.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[Greasemonkey does not work with jQuery 1.4.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207199/greasemonkey-and-jquery-1-4-2-not-working/3207310#3207310)

Use jQuery 1.3.2.

Note that you will have to uninstall and then reinstall your script to ensure that the correct jQuery file is copied to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, there's always the option of not using jQuery here, since only Greasemonkey has implemented the `@require` rules.

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll('script[src$="swa.py"]'), 
    d = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="__swa"]'); 

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    s[i].parentNode.removeChild(s[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
    d[i].style.display = 'none';
}

document.body.style.padding = '0px';
```

`document.querySelectorAll` is only available in IE8 and above, but that's alright here. This script has not tested, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have to wait a couple of days until I fly on that airline again.  I will let you know how it works when I'm flying.